# How to make Tab move the cursor between only input fields ignoring everything else?

Tags: macos, keyboard, mojave, shortcut

I have seen setting like this in "preferences", but cannot find it. I am using mojave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings → Keyboard → shortcuts → Full keyboard access. <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> is the shortcut for the same.

[image: Settings → Keyboard → shortcuts → Full keyboard access]